# Dynamic change Traefik frontend configuration in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik, api-gateway

I run Traefik in Docker using `docker-compose`

```
version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    command: --api --docker --docker.watch
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        - ./traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml

  frontend:
    image: platform/frontend
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:frontend.docker.localhost"
```

Documentation says that there are 2 types of configurations:

- The static Træfik configuration which is loaded only at the beginning.
- The dynamic Træfik configuration which can be hot-reloaded (no need to restart the process).

The dynamic configuration includes Frontends.

How can I change `traefik.frontend.rule` for my docker service without restarting it?

Let's say I need change it to : `traefik.frontend.rule=Host:home.docker.localhost`

Answer (score 1):

I think is a *docker swarm* ability. You can update a service in *swarm* with `docker service update`, but you cant do it without a swarm cluster. 
With docker service update you can change labels, images, with the **rolling update** swarm feature.